# update query not updating the table

Tags: php, mysql

I am executing an update query in my script. It's returning true but the update query does not update the table. Here is the query. What i'm missing here?

```
$connection = db::factory('mysql');
$query='update bookings SET date="'.$date.'",time_from="'.$time_from.'",time_to="'.$time_to.'",status="'.$status.'" where booker_id="'.$booker_id.'"';
if(mysql_query($query)) {
   echo "success"; exit;
   return true;
} else {
   echo "fail"; exit;
   return false;
}
```

Here is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time_from` time NOT NULL,
  `time_to` time NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `booker_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;
```

Comment: Please show the resulting query string and your table structure.

Comment: You should look into PDO or MySQLi with prepared statements as mysql_ functions have been deprecated.

Comment: Don't use the mysql_* use the mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: This may be due to the constraints in the table given by you. you should show the table structure.

Comment: Added the table structure now..

Comment: Please show table structure and resulting query.

Comment: what is the value of `$booker_id`, as i suspect that it is updating successfully but not actually matching the records. print out `$query` and see exactly what is being sent to the db

Comment: replace `echo "fail"; exit;` with `echo "fail: ".$query; exit;` to view the actual executed query, and double check if the `booker_id` from the where clause actually exists...

Comment: @DannyHearnah:- u r right...its working.. Please put ur comment in answer, i'll accept it

Comment: @kirankumar im glad it helped, i have added my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is the value of `$booker_id`, as i suspect that it is updating successfully but not actually matching the records. print out `$query` and see exactly what is being sent to the db

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $query='update `bookings` SET `date`="'.$date.'",`time_from`="'.$time_from.'",`time_to`="'.$time_to.'",`status`="'.$status.'" where `booker_id`="'.$booker_id.'"';


    $rs = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    if($rs) {
       echo "success"; exit;
       return true;
    } else {
       echo "fail"; exit;
       return false;
    }
```

Hope it will help

Comment: please echo the query above and check the value is getting or not

Answer (score 0):

And the ` till on column name as you have column name date and date is a datatype of column and reserved keywork in mysql use this:

```
$query='update `bookings` SET `date`="'.$date.'",`time_from`="'.$time_from.'",`time_to`="'.$time_to.'",`status`="'.$status.'" where `booker_id`="'.$booker_id.'"';
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns true because there was no error.
But Mysql didn't find any entry to update, because none is corresponding to your conditions.
You should return the whole query to check it, and try to execute it by hand with phpMyAdmin.
+1 for the ` around the date column.

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) just returns true since the query run successfully. I would recommend to get the number of rows updated/modified to check whether this query updated any row or not. So use [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) immediately after executing update query.
Note: mysql_* queries are depricated, So Try to use any of [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)